# Broken pipe when running backup script on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tar

I have written a simple bash where I'm connecting to an external storage via `curlftpfs` and then running `tar` in it to make a backup of my filesystem (ubuntu 18). It looks something like this:

```
curlftpfs -o ssl,no_verify_peer,utf8,allow_other ftp://username:password@personaladdress.myfritz.net:61111/WD/Backup $BACKUP_DIR

tar -cvpzf $BACKUP_DIR/backup-$DATE.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/mnt --exclude=$BACKUP_DIR --exclude=/dev --exclude=/sys <other excludes> /
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. It will create an empty tar with a size of 0 on my backup-drive and I will get following error message:

```
gzip: stdout: Input/output error
gzip: write error: Input/output error
tar: /mntbackup/backup-2019-03-06-001111.tar.gz: Funktion write fehlgeschlagen: Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What is the reason and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try your tar command without mounted the remote `$BACKUP_DIR`?

Comment: Yes, it works if it not mounted - so the connection seems to be the issue

Comment: You could try to test it step by step. Do you have the another device in your network which has more CPU power and which you can use? Maybe the problem is related to the not very powerful fritzbox.

Comment: I just changed the logic to not use curlftpfs anymore but to just transfer the single file with ftp to my fritzbox. That works at least :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find an answer for the issue but I found another way to transfer my backup. I'm simply using `lftp` and just doing a `put` like this:

```
lftp ftp://<user>:<password>@<host>
put <backup-filename>.tar.gz
bye
```